# what is equivalent of vb6 vbfromcode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

We are converting our vb6 code to vb.net and facing problem in **vbFromCode** which tell that form is closing from code, not by user action. Please tell me about what is equivalent in vb.net

Comment: Presumably you mean `vbFormCode` not `vbFromCode`

Comment: There is no direct equivalent, ensure you always call a method to unload the form and do whatever you need in there.

Answer (score 0):

See CloseReason.* values of e.CloseReason in the form's FormClosing event

Comment: I have not found any equivalent in e.CloseReason. There are total 7 reason in e.CloseReason, But which one is equivalent to vbFromCode

Comment: How do you classify "close reason" as "from code". Somehow all closing reasons that I have encountered are classified "UserClosing (3)".

Comment: I want to distinguish whether formClosing event is called due to close function calling from within the code or user press the close button

Comment: I think you'd be better off assigning a value to a variable from inside your function then check its value inside the formclosing event.